# The printed string is different from the string I gave input to- c programming

Tags: c, string

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>


int main()
{
    char word[25];
    while (scanf("%s", word)!=EOF){

    int cp=0, cm=0, i, j;

    //check palindrome
    for (i=0; i<strlen(word); i++){
        if (word[i]!=word[strlen(word)-1-i])
            break;
    }
    if (i==strlen(word)) cp=1;

    //check mirror
    for (i=0, j=strlen(word)-1; i<strlen(word); i++, j--){
        int dec=1;
        switch(word[i]){
            case 'A':
                dec = word[j]='A'? 1:0;
                break;
            case 'E':
                dec = word[j]='3'? 1:0;
                break;
            case 'H':
                dec = word[j]='H'? 1:0;
                break;
            case 'I':
                dec = word[j]='I'? 1:0;
                break;
            case 'J':
                dec = word[j]='L'? 1:0;
                break;
            case 'L':
                dec = word[j]='J'? 1:0;
                break;
            case 'M':
                dec = word[j]='M'? 1:0;
                break;
            case 'O':
                dec = word[j]='O'? 1:0;
                break;
            case 'S':
                dec = word[j]='2'? 1:0;
                break;
            case 'T':
                dec = word[j]='T'? 1:0;
                break;
            case 'U':
                dec = word[j]='U'? 1:0;
                break;
            case 'V':
                dec = word[j]='V'? 1:0;
                break;
            case 'W':
                dec = word[j]='W'? 1:0;
                break;
            case 'X':
                dec = word[j]='X'? 1:0;
                break;
            case 'Y':
                dec = word[j]='Y'? 1:0;
                break;
            case 'Z':
                dec = word[j]='5'? 1:0;
                break;
            case '1':
                dec = word[j]='1'? 1:0;
                break;
            case '2':
                dec = word[j]='S'? 1:0;
                break;
            case '3':
                dec = word[j]='E'? 1:0;
                break;
            case '5':
                dec = word[j]='Z'? 1:0;
                break;
            case '8':
                dec = word[j]='8'? 1:0;
                break;
            default:
                dec = 0;
                break;
        }
        if (!dec) break;
    }
    if (i==strlen(word)) cm=1;
    printf("%d %d %d\n", i, j, strlen(word));

    if (cp==1 && cm==1){
        printf("%s is a mirrored palindrome.\n", word);
    }
    else if (cp){
        printf("%s is a regular palindrome.\n", word);
    }
    else if(cm){
        printf("%s is a mirrored string.\n", word);
    }
    else if(cp==0 && cm==0) {
        printf("%s is not a palindrome.\n", word);
    }
}
}
```

I am giving strings using scanf("%s", word) But when I am printing the same program latter at the end using printf("%s", word) the string gets modified partially and doesn't print the whole string correctly.

Input example

MMMMM
ATOYOTA
NOTAPALINDROME
ISAPALINILAPASI

Output:

3 1 5
MM��� is a regular palindrome.
4 2 7
ATO���� is a regular palindrome.
0 13 14
NOTAPALINDROME is not a palindrome.
3 11 15
ISAPALINILAP��� is a regular palindrome.

Comment: I think you mean  dec = word[j] =='A'? 1:0; instead of dec = word[j] = 'A'? 1:0; That is after the expression word[j] there must be the comparison instead of the assignment.

Comment: No need to have that big switch-case: just compare word[i] with word[j]. Furthermore, you don't need to iterate on all the string, but just on half of it (the second half is "covered" by j).